# Uploading a file to a network server from intranet, should the file name be included in the path?

Tags: angular, rest, user-interface, intranet

I am using a rest tool to upload a file from the intranet onto a network server and receiving the error:

"Access to the path '\\\servername.com\subfolder1\subfolder2\file_name' is denied"

My question is, should the file name be appearing in the "path" error, or should it simply be trying to access to "\\subfolder2\\"?

My expectation is that the error i'm receiving is due to a permissions issue with the service account we are impersonating to make the call... but I want to confirm that the file path being used should in fact include the file name as it is now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is yes... the file name should be in the path when attempting to upload from an intranet to a network server.